# Windows won't boot, recovery disk stalls, booting from linux usb reports failed to mount - input/output error

Tags: windows-7, boot, chkdsk

Here are the steps taken so far:

1. Try booting in safe mode, and boot without networking -> Stalls at loading classpnp.sys
2. Try booting in safe mode, do a repair -> Stalls no error
3. Boot from windows 7 image on usb and do a repair -> gets to the point where you select your operating system and it hangs (doesn't show an os either)
4. Boot from Ubuntu 12 image -> works, but gives error that the main hard drive can't be mounted, "Failed to mount '/dev/sda3': Input/output error" and suggests I run chkdsk from windows.

I'm not setup to take the drive out and hook it up to another computer, I'm about to try ntfsfix, but any other way to run chkdsk?

Comment: a few more details while running ntfsfix, the first line of output was "Mounting volumne... Failed to read $UpCase, unexpected length (20480 != 131072)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use your Windows 7 installation CD to boot-up, in the first screen press the shortcut key Shift+F10. The Command Promp windows will apper. Now you can use the chkdsk command.

Comment: So this is a netbook, there is no cd/dvd drive, hence using the usb stick. Would this shortcut to the command prompt work when booting from that? and when you say first screen, would that be the first non-bios screen i get to?

Comment: Yes it will work for sure. You can press it from the screen of choosing the language and keyboard layout.

Comment: awesome trick, chkdsk is running woohoo!